# What KeyEvent.vk_ is mapped to the App key?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I use KeyBinding to capture the user's keyboard event on a JPanel. However, I failed to find the KeyEvent.vk_ which stands for the Application key. The Application key is like this [image]

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is this key OS or hardware specific?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels. No, I just want to capture it when it's typed and tell the user what kind of key event has been captured.

Comment: Is that a "popup menu key"?  Can you get a better picture?

Comment: @MadProgrammer. Yeah, you are right. It's between alt and ctrl or win and ctrl in common.

Comment: @user1803551. Sorry for late response. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_CONTEXT_MENU` is the "Constant for the Microsoft Windows Context Menu key".